# Monitoring resource use in Jboss in JMeter performance test

Tags: jboss, jmeter, jconsole

We are performing some JMeter tests on a JBoss 4.0.5 deployed web app. We want to integrate the resource usage on the application on the server (memory, threads, etc) with the JMeter response time results.

We have found a tutorial for doing that with Tomcat: http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=java&seqNum=273 and we want to know if it could be done with JBoss.

One alternative is doing resource usage monitoring by hand, using jconsole or something similar, but we prefer something automated and integrated.

Regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JBoss includes Tomcat, so yes.  Instead of the `/manager/status?XML=true` URL path mentioned in the article, use `/status?XML=true`.  That should be it.