# How to deploy jmetter in jboss?

Tags: jboss, jmeter

I have a problem i have to deploy jmeter with jboss.
Does anyone know useful link or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

And what [says google about this](http://www.google.by/search?rls=en&q=deploy+jmeter+jboss)?
At least this one: [Monitoring resource use in Jboss in JMeter performance test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386692/monitoring-resource-use-in-jboss-in-jmeter-performance-test).